# unable to change permissions

Tags: nautilus, chmod

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,

I want a text file not to be executed when opened in nautilus or dash.

ls-l shows this line for the regarding file

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1310149 Sep 20 10:28
```

then i run

```
sudo chmod -v -x /path/to/file/file.txt
```

and recieve:

```
mode of ‘/path/to/file/file.txt’ changed from 0777 (rwxrwxrwx) to 0666 (rw-rw-rw-)
```

ls -l again:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1310149 Sep 20 10:29
```

When i open 'sudo nautilus' and change the checkbox in the properties-menu of the file it immediatley changes back to "checked".

Comment: where is the file located?

Comment: The file is probably on an NTFS or FAT/FAT32 volume mounted in such a way as to treat all files as executable. Those filesystems don't generally support Unix-style executable permissions and are usually mounted to make it so executable permissions are either always on or always off. If you [edit] your question to include the name of the volume containing the file (or the full path of the file) and also the output of `mount, this could be confirmed (or refuted) and an answer could probably be given.

Comment: I recommend also explaining what you mean by "I want a text file not to be executed." (You can provide this info in an [edit] too.) Do you just mean, you want to open it in a text editor when you double-click on it in Nautilus (the graphical file browser), instead of an attempt being made to run it? If so, this may be achieved without actually changing its permissions, depending on whether or not you need to run many other text executables by double-clicking on them.

Comment: editing is done, it is on an /dev/sdb1 (ntfs) (/ is on dev/sda1). Also i recently added /dev/sdb1 on fstab, problem occured scince then. There are also some issues with nautilus at startup scince, i'll have to figure this out. Thank you for help

Comment: Permissions on NTFS are set when *mounting* not on the files itself. Your problem is related to editing /etc/fstab so can you edit into the question the contents of fstab?

Comment: Solved. btw is rw and noexec redundant in that case? Still have a nautilus Error at startup

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing the Options in /etc/fstab

```
UUID=3B08A23B4D3D4F2A /media/$path/$volume ntfs auto,rw,noexec 0 0
UUID=0EAB6A7871E3FE21 /media/$path/$volume ntfs auto,rw,noexec 0 0
```